# Is it possible to specify browserify config in package.json (other than transform)?

Tags: npm, browserify, package.json

In package.json we can specify browserify transforms like this:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": ["babelify"]
}
```

Is it possible to set other config like `debug`, `detectGlobals`, input source file, output file, etc. For example, something like:

```
"browserify": {
  "debug": true,
  "detectGlobals": false,

  "transform": ["babelify"]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't found an answer to this yet:

Yes, it is and quite simple. You were very close. here's the example from the browserify README.md

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
  }
}
```

read more [here](https://github.com/babel/babelify#user-content-faq).

Comment: It doesn't work. I added to package.json: "browserify": {"list":true} and nothing happens. I see that only 2 parameters can be set to package.json: https://github.com/browserify/browserify-handbook#packagejson